# How to make 3D blocks video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, effects

I know how to use `tile` and `stereo3d` or `overlay` filters to make 2d blocks (mosaic) video but i can't figure out a way to slice video into multi parts and arrange it into 3d blocks just like just like in the image [image]

How can i do this? Is it possible with ffmpeg?

Comment: See the [perspective](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#perspective) filter.

Comment: I editted for more accurate

Comment: after 2 weeks.I still can't figure out how to do